# the best detect and recognition method

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, i am building my vision system to detect and recognition objects ..

firstly, i did object 3D model cloud points Using [Roboearth Stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth/Tutorials/Record%20an%20object%20model)

then tried to detect it with [roboearth detector](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth/Tutorials/Using%20recorded%20models%20for%20object%20detection) package but it isn't the best because:

- detect Only texture objects and i have One colored objects
- red marker not located all the time
- can't detect the object when turning it reversal
- i tried to add 2 models to detect them in the same time but it didn't work

i will make some reasoning relations on these objects after that in Knowrob

So, i want a help to choose the best method to detection and recognition objects
i am reading in bigg_detector now and searching at others ..

any help to choose the best detect and recognition method ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49444/the-best-detect-and-recognition-method/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-11-29

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Salma,

There are several object detectors/recognizers that you could test to have an idea of the complexity of the task and figure out which one better fits your needs:

- http://ecto.willowgarage.com/recognition/user.html: provides you LINE-MOD (which should detect non-textured objects), TOD and transparent objects detection
- http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/#recognition-tutorial: PCL is indeed a powerful option to detect non-textured objects
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/blort_ros: monocular model based object detector (see tutorials in http://www.ros.org/wiki/blort_ros/Tutorials)
- http://personalrobotics.ri.cmu.edu/projects/moped.php
- and many more out there ...

HTH

---

Originally posted by [Jordi Pages](https://answers.ros.org/users/626/jordi-pages/) with karma: 245 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-30**:
@Jordi Pages  thanks alot ,, very useful links ... i am building a system can deal with roboearth server
So i nees OWL description of the model to be knowledge in Knowrob  thats why i used roboearth stack ,, i don't know if I must use it to detect and recognition the object or can use any method

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, there is no "best" object detector.  Each one works best on some objects, and less well on others.  If all of your objects are in that set that it works well on, then that's the "best" detector.  Without knowing more about your objects, and your application, it's hard to give more concrete advice.

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-30**:
@Bill Smart ok thanks bill ,, i am building system can deal with Roboearth Server to share knowledge between robots .. my application is to recognition objects and make reasoning operation to find what is missing component on the table ,, so i am restricted by OWL description of models as i think